# Extract values using regular expression extractor JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to JMeter and I am trying to extract two values using regular expression extractor. The output below is taken out from my browser developer tool in the Params tab. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
execution: e1s1
lt: LT-834935-bEjV0TiHLqi0T6kQddxklS7GoKgOhO
```

Comment: If those are in request params, why do you want to extract them as you send thme ? If not can you please show the raw response that contains them ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all understand how Correlation in JMeter works..

It is the process of capturing and storing the dynamic response from the server and passing it on to subsequent requests. A response is considered dynamic when it can return different data for each iterating request, occasionally affecting successive requests.

The parameters what you have seen are dynamic , you have to identify from which request's response these values are coming.

Use regular expression extractors to extract dynamic values and pass it on to the subsequent requests.

References :
[Jmeter Extraction using Regular Expressions](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/09/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)